# Cannot set/get the property of extended class in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter, extending-classes

I have an issue related to setting or getting the value of the extended class in `Typescript` and `angular 2`.

I have a class A with these properties:

```
export class A {
    protected name: string;

    set setName(name: string) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    get getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I am extending the class A from B as :

```
export class B extends A implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.setName('User');
    }
}
```

This returns the error as :

```
this.setName is not a function
```

I suppose it is telling that there is no any function called `setName` in class B.

**How do i set the value to be used in the function that's extending the Class A? What is the best way as the constructor initialization didn't worked for me.**

I also cannot create the new instance of the class B and set the value. If i am wrong any where could anyone correct me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a setter, it should be

```
this.setName = 'User';
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was doing the wrong way. (facepalm)

Comment: We have all been there :D